# file url issue in PHP

Tags: php, html

the below script, when I reference the URL, if I shorten it in any way, it fails to locate the files, however when left full-length, it outputs the full server url to the link and the href - is there a correct way to change the included directory to prevent this?

```
<?php

function getFiles($dir)
{
    $arr=scandir($dir);
    $res=array();
    foreach ($arr as $item)
    {
        if ($item=='..' || $item=='.'){continue;}
        $path=$dir.'/'.$item;
        if (is_dir($path))
        {
            $res=array_merge($res,getFiles($path));
        }
        else
        {
            $res[$path]=filemtime($path);
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

$files=getFiles('/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/Manuals/');
arsort($files);
$files=array_slice(array_keys($files),0,11);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference those files as relative to the script's `__FILE__` and use `dirname(...)` to get the full, actual path.  Then you can output the relative URLs in the html:

```
 $files=getFiles(dirname('Manuals'));
 arsort($files);
 $files=array_slice(array_keys($files),0,11);
 foreach ($files as $file)
 {
     $file = pathinfo($file)['filename'];
     echo '<a href="Manuals/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br />';
 }
```

Comment: getting close, the code you put actually outputs the entire server's contents (base directory of the php file) however placing it as /Manuals instead gives me a basedir security error

Comment: moved php file into the manuals directory instead of root, removing the href manuals, and it will work now. the actual PHP file gets listed in the list, however since it only shows the most recent few, and the php file won't be editted, its not an issue. Thanks for the help!